# Switch between components in React Navigation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I'm trying to use React Navigation from this tutorial:

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/auth-flow.html

The code works correctly but when I split it to multiple components I can call the Login component from the Root but I can't navigate to other screens from Login component because my stack is defined in Root login and Login component doesn't know stack.
Here is my code:

App.js:

```
    import Login from './components/Login';

    class SignInScreen extends React.Component {
        static navigationOptions = {
          title: 'Please sign in',
        };

        render() {
          return (
                <Login />
          );
        };
    }
....

      const AppStack = createStackNavigator({ Home: HomeScreen, Other: OtherScreen });
      const AuthStack = createStackNavigator({ SignIn: SignInScreen });

      export default createAppContainer(createSwitchNavigator(
        {
          AuthLoading: AuthLoadingScreen,
          App: AppStack,
          Auth: AuthStack,
        },
        {
          initialRouteName: 'AuthLoading',
        }
      ));
```

Login.js:

```
class Login extends Component {

    render(){
        return(
                 <View>
                    ........
                 <View>
        );
    }
    _signInAsync = async () => {
        await AsyncStorage.setItem('userToken', 'abc');
        this.props.navigation.navigate('App');
      };

};

export default Login;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `withNavigation` HOC to access the stack from the Login component.

Read more about it here: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/4.x/with-navigation

Comment: The link is dead.